# Rails command working , rails -v shows Rails 4.0.0 , gem list rails shows 3.2.13

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

Rails command is working . rails -v shows 4.0.0 . gem list rails shows 3.2.13 . I want to work on rails 3.2.13 , when i tried to uninstall rails 4.0.0 it says *gem "rails" is not installed* .What should i do so that rails -v shows 3.2.13 and rails 4 get uninstalled ?

Comment: Can you do 'which rails'?

Comment: I do not use rvm , but i can easily switch between different versions.

Comment: which rails shows - /usr/local/bin/rails

Comment: the best way to solve your problem is to install rvm (ruby version manager) it's easy and it will help you a lot to manage your projects, i think no one today don't use a version manager in his work, you can check the tuto below in my answer it's very interesting

Comment: You should be using bundler, and `bundle exec rails -v` will always load the rails version as defined in your `Gemfile`

Answer (score 1):

It's because the Rails binary actually loads itself via the `railties` gem. The last two lines of `/usr/local/bin/rails` looks something like:

```
gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

You need to run:

```
gem uninstall railties -v 4.0.0
```

Assuming you have Rails & Railties 3.2.13 installed, `rails -v` should now return `Rails 3.2.13`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want remove rails 4, if you are already using rvm you should easily switch between ruby/rails versions without any problem, if you don't know rvm i recommend you to read [why-you-should-use-rvm](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-use-rvm/)

if you should remove obligatory rails 4.0.0 try this command :

```
gem uninstall rails --version 4.0.0
```

if this can't solve your problem please add more details in your question

Comment: I can easily switch between different versions of rails as you said . I created a new app by writing - **rails _3.2.13_ new <appname>** and it is working fine . But my doubt is , when i do **rails -v it** shows 4.0.0 and when i do **gem list rails** , it shows rails 3.2.13 , i do not get it

Comment: One more thing , when i tried to uninstall rails 4.0.0 using ** gem uninstall rails -v 4.0.0 ** it uninstalled rails 3.2.13 . Please give me some pointers.

Comment: when you are doing rails -v and gem list rails are you in the same directory ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the best way to use rvm https://rvm.io/rvm/install
I had the same problem a week ago.

try `gem uninstall rails -v=4.0.0.`
or

```
gem uninstall rails
```

then install rvm using:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

and then

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

and

```
gem install rails --version '~> 3.2.0'
```